# What does 'smattered' mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

> Forbidden Forest looked as though it had been enchanted, each tree **smattered** with silver, and Hagrid's cabin looked like an iced cake.

I looked up the word '**smatter**':

> v.tr.
>
> 1. To speak (a language) without fluency: smatters Russian.
> 2. To study or approach superficially; dabble in.
>
> v.intr.
>
> To prattle: smattered on about her vacation.

None of them seem to fit for the context. What does it truly mean here?

Comment: A synonym would be **spattered**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions that you supplied give some indication of the author's intent when she said, '... each tree smattered with silver'. You may have got closer to the answer had you looked up 'smattering'.

> Smattering: A smattering of something is a very small amount of it. (collinsdictionary.com)

So the author is saying that the trees had small splashes of silver on them, but not nearly enough to coat them completely.

Comment: It also means "to make dirty, to stain".